# How to output exception error in Scala/Play

Tags: java, scala, gzip

I'm completely new to Scala, and have inherited a project where I am trying to compress a file via gzip and upload it to s3.

I am getting an error telling me `java.lang.Exception: Problem zipping file`
which is the output of `throw new Exception("Problem zipping file" + tempFilePath)`

Unfortunately, I'm not clear on what is in the exception and why gzip would be failing. This is on a windows machine, and gzip is available from the command line, and has been included in the global.scala file with `import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter`

The entire code for the upload and compress is

```
def compressAndUpload(tempFilePath: String, dstFileName: String, mimeType: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    "gzip -9 " + tempFilePath ! match {

      case 0 =>
        val gzipTempFilePath = tempFilePath + ".gz"

        val bucket = S3(System.getenv("S3_BUCKET_NAME"))

        // Get incoming file as a byte array
        val byteArray = scalax.io.Resource.fromFile(gzipTempFilePath).byteArray
        // Write to bucket
        val result = bucket + BucketFile(dstFileName, mimeType, byteArray, Some(PUBLIC_READ), Some(Map("Content-Encoding" -> "gzip")))

        result.map { unit =>
          Logger.info("S3 file saved: " + dstFileName)
          // Delete the file
          new File(gzipTempFilePath).delete()
          true
        }.recover {
          case S3Exception(status, code, message, originalXml) => throw new Exception("Error: " + message)
        }

      case _ =>
        throw new Exception("Problem zipping file" + tempFilePath)
    }
  }
```

Comment: try 'scala> def foo( f : () => Unit) : Unit = try {
     | f()
     | } catch { case e : Exception => println("H" + e.getStackTrace) }
foo: (f: () => Unit)Unit'

Comment: your title seems misleading. You ask "what is in the exception?" as far as I understand its the exception that you simply throw so what can it be. There is no exception happening, executing gzip just returns something else than 0. You can maybe check what is it and  try to find out what's wrong, or use something different than `!`, (for example print the lines that this command produces  when executed).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the string I was looking for was in the exception, just not being output.

```
case _ =>
        var e = new Exception("Problem zipping file" + tempFilePath)
        println(e.getStackTraceString)
        throw e
    }
```